# Exhaustive List of World Provinces in Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, frontend

A client wants a web form that uses a drop down for the users country and another drop down that automatically list ALL states/provinces within the selected country. I can implement the logic of the form; that is not the problem. The problem is the massive data that would be involved and possible complications that could arise from such a setup. I have already informed the client that the requirement is a dumb idea, not cost effective, and that it would require a database because there can be thousands of provinces worldwide.

Is the request advisable or good practice?
Are there any examples of this form setup online?
Are there any api's or web services that can accomplish this?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Whether it's advisable depends on what the client needs to do with it, I guess. (Most likely though, it is a dumb idea. Who fricking cares about choosing a province when usually, your postal code will already give you all the information necessary, *including* the province?)

Comment: The form is for users to request information and the client thinks that they will get great metrics if they can see exactly where the request are coming from. I advised them to simply use text boxes so the user can fill in their own location but he client is being very pushy.

Comment: My $0.02: Such dev is pointless unless you are apple or some huge company who wants to reach their users. If client insists because they have the money, just load the required data: list of countries and load each list of regions using json, giving the user only the info he needs... oh, and be patient listing all the regions of every single country in a DB, some has to do a lot of googlesearching hehe

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a simpler, easier, better way to accomplish whatever your client is trying to do. If he's trying to make it convenient for the user to select a province, then he's failed because it's almost always easier to type in "CA" than look through a list for "California". If he's trying to ensure that the package gets delivered to the correct place always, as @Pekka mentions, postal code is more fail proof. Explain this to him because solving this problem is probably not worth your time.

Comment: @JusticeGödelConder As far as metrics, rolling out your own analytics is almost always a bad idea, unless you're willing to spend a lot of time making something pretty robust. You can collect all sorts of useful information passively: IP address, geocoded lat-long, etc. I doubt what he wants is nearly as useful as what other analytics packages might provide. And for your client to be asking a user to enter information manually is a pain for the user and should be rarely done.

Comment: Just to be clear: This requirement would be a piece of cake if they only wanted something like all the states in the US listed but they want all the provinces of all nations like Algeria, Benin, and Qatar as well. I don't know where to begin with a request this expansive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to deal with similar setup in our website.  After much discussion, we settled on a subset of this: the states/provinces are only populated for a small number of countries (about 10, I think) and for all other countries a simple text box is displayed to enter the county/state/province.

The data is stored in the database and is loaded with the page in the beginning and javascript is then formatted from the php.  The site is http://www.ooklnet.com - click on "join" in the top right corner, then select "individual".  Try changing the country to USA, Canada, United Kingdom, Mexico, India (or a few other ones).